# numpy.float64 type and is_integer() issues

Tags: python, numpy, integer, sage

I am writting some python code in sagemath. I just want to parse some values to check if they are integers or not. I'm doing it with is_integer() function. However, only some numbers are matched as integers.

I have this array:

```
[[  1.26975000e+03   7.02493619e-14  -1.65645275e-13   5.00000000e+00
    2.50000000e+00   3.54050123e-13  -2.91373674e+00   1.06841761e+00]
 [ -5.00000000e+00   9.49393038e-01   5.00000000e+00  -5.00000000e+00
   -1.33475906e+00  -2.51708718e+00   4.98747803e-01  -2.21681235e+00]
 [  3.13790751e+00   4.17443857e-14   2.09099026e+00   1.48894747e+00
   -1.98140835e-01  -3.11027406e+00  -1.73743687e+00   5.68322944e-02]
 [ -5.00000000e+00  -5.15698595e-14   2.46634986e+00  -3.01863014e-01
   -1.64657626e+00   2.47085900e+00  -5.88213961e-01  -2.89145373e-02]
 [  5.00000000e+00   5.12235598e-01  -1.48149016e+00   2.94309857e-01
    4.75000000e+00  -5.33661417e-01   3.43055265e-01  -4.12203856e+00]
 [ -1.22979595e-01  -2.99512587e-01   2.86838294e+00  -2.54014737e-01
   -1.07441346e+00   2.81962997e+00   1.28837244e-01   2.07388351e-01]
 [ -1.57036190e+00   2.13573146e-01  -7.37436867e-01   5.22145920e+00
    2.78805312e+00   2.34402605e+00  -1.09099026e+00  -3.34248259e-02]
 [ -2.44284969e+00  -4.44168609e+00   9.51259207e-01   7.49320230e-01
    4.77326511e-01   2.99085430e+00  -2.39859298e+00  -1.96715999e+00]]
```

I have this code:

```py
for row in dct_block:
    for frec in row:
        print frec,frec.is_integer(),type(frec)
```

And i'm getting these results:

```
1269.75 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
7.02493618832e-14 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
-1.65645275274e-13 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
5.0 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
2.5 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
3.54050122553e-13 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
-2.91373674111 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
1.06841760838 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
-5.0 True <type 'numpy.float64'>
0.94939303763 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
5.0 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
...
```

As you can see, only the number "-5" is matched as integer. There are some others, such as two "5.0", which should be matched as well.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried in Python3 and for me `is_integer` works with float64 from numpy. Maybe you can post a complete runable example.

Comment: Try printing `repr(frec)` instead of `frec`. I suspect you'll see values that are close to integers, but aren't exact integers. The printing of `frec` is rounding to 12 significant digits and so hiding the imprecision.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks!!! That was the issue. This is some output with repr: 5.0000000000000124 False <type 'numpy.float64'>
5.0 True <type 'numpy.float64'>

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the array in the question is the result of a computation
using floating-point values, in which case some non-integers entries
might have turned out non-integer due to rounding errors.

Consider using exact numbers for the computation, rather than
floating-point approximations, if that is an option. Note that
one can use Sage number types as data types for NumPy arrays.

If some of the computations involve transcendent functions,
Arb might give a way to work in arbitrary precision.

Finally, replacing `is_integer` by a test whether the distance
to the nearest integer is less than some threshold might be an
option, if one suspects this might be due to rounding errors.